# Launching BIG site - HELP!

Tags: discussion, support, area-51, site-proposal

My group and I have a site that we feel could seriously benefit from the SE2.0 infrastructure, and we feel that we could draw in at least 100 seriously avid users and a crowd of at least 10,000 contributors, but we're not sure that we can maintain the required velocity to obtain a complete site using the Area51 system.

What advice can you give me about launching this site that I haven't told you anything about, and getting it to have a successful launch velocity?

Unfortunately I'm not an avid user of the SE2.0 infrastructure and don't know enough of how it functions to know how successful I can deem the site to be in the end.

(Note to reddmoney ~ This is a little more of a reasonable question that we can answer around here)

Comment: All the experts on Yahoo Answers? I'm sure we can handle that...

Comment: Your last two paragraphs make it pretty clear to me that this is not the right place for your question.

Comment: Future readers: note that balpha's comment was made just before the original post was edited.

Comment: Thanks @PopularDemand ~ @balpha we were trying to help, maybe this revised question will assist the user in understanding that.

Comment: Also, I realized I added an unnecessary --`k`-- in the final line. The name I meant to quote was `reddmoney` and I apologize profusely. Can someone remove that K for me that has natural edit ability? ~ Thanks Pekka!

Comment: Don't go away mad.

Comment: @user156848: I would invite you to read about the Area 51 process for creating new sites: http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq. We no longer offer a service to create sites that you would own or exercise *any* control over.  Stack Exchange sites can only be created via the democratic, community-driven process at Area 51.

Answer (score 4):

> What assurances do we have with area51.stackexchange?

None.

> And how much control of the site will we have?

None, at least not in the really important decisions.

The up side is that SE takes care of the *huge* task of developing, maintaining, and administering the web sites. If your interest is to get a community running on a top-notch platform, and you think the people you bring have the momentum to get the proposal running, it's probably the best way to go. If you don't want to give up control of the way the site is run, you can use one of the [Stack Overflow clones](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones) and run the whole operation yourself- with all the work that this entails.

Answer (score 0):

The assurance you have is the level of community that you build.  If the site gets no velocity then your assurance probably is not high.  If you want a guarantee then you should probably look at launching something on your own.

If you already know your audience you can create an Area51 site proposal and invite them to follow, commit, and beta test it.  That should give you quite a level of velocity to get it off the ground.

Comment: I strongly suspect he is familiar with SE1.0 sites, meaning wanting to launch one of his own but on SE